# Is this function biLipschitz?

Tags: analysis, inequality

Let $\Omega = (1,2) \times (1,2) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and define $f$ on $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ as follows:
$$
f(x,y) = (x + y, x + y^2).
$$
Does there exist a constant $C>0$ such that for all $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ in $\Omega$,
$$
C\|(x,y) - (x',y')\| \leq \|f(x,y) - f(x',y')\|?
$$

Answer (score 0):

The function $z= y^2-y$ is increasing on $[1,2]$, with the derivative bounded from below by $1$. Therefore its inverse, say $y=\psi(z)$, is $1$-Lipschitz on $[0,2]$. (Of course you can write $\psi$ down explicitly, but this is not needed.)

If $u=x+y$ and $v=x+y^2$, then $y=\psi(v-u)$ and $x=u-\psi(v-u)$. This is a formula for $f^{-1}$, which is evidently Lipschitz.